# is it any 'simler' for this import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router-dom, react-native-navigation

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
```

how to use this on native any smiler `npm` module is it have.
can I use

```
import {  } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

for this use

Comment: Are you using `react-router-dom` or `react-navigation`? Can you clarify what any specific issue is? What you are trying to accomplish? What you've tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
import { useRoute  } from '@react-navigation/native';

const route = useRoute()
```

then you can access

```
const ScreenName = route.name
```

that is name of your Screen Prop